# Using Javascript to save files in Photoshop without a prompt?

Tags: javascript, save, photoshop, prompt

I am using a simple script to edit an existing image.

No matter what I do, a save prompt always comes up. I want this to be 100% automated.

save() gives me a saveAs prompt to save it as a copy.
close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES) just gives me a generic "Do you wish to save before closing?" box that I still need to select Yes on.
saveAs() gives me the same as save(), except I can toddle the "As copy" option off... but that still doesn't help.

Comment: Before other clueless people downvote this further out of ignorance, please understand that the scripting language in Adobe Photoshop is javascript. Yes, javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
// where fPath is your file path
// jpgSaveOptions.quality controls the quality of the jpeg

// save out the image as jpeg
var jpgFile = new File(fPath);
jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
jpgSaveOptions.quality = 12;

activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

There is a known bug with compatibility issues of Photoshop, but I dodn't think this is it.

And just for the record Photoshop can be scripted in either Applescript, JavaScript or Visual Basic

Comment: Thanks, the key was adding `true` as a third argument to `activeDocument.saveAs`.