# how to make layers combination in photoshop

Tags: combinations, permutation, batch-processing, photoshop-script

I have multiple layers in a file and i want to create combinations of those layers. Like layer1 and layer 2,   layer 1 and layer 3
see the example.
[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If5H1.jpg)

I want to automate this process like u can see in image that i have places first layer to be used on left side of the image and then i need a tool which can turn off the layers on right side one by one and save the image like layer01-layer02.jpg , layer01-layer03.jpg.

Kindly help me in this.

**EDIT:**

a script on github helped me solve the problem
[Photoshop script that separately saves top level layers inside the selected group](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/013a223e94ba0fb9a2a0)

just place the layer which u want to keep in all images outside the group, and all other images in a layer group.
then select the group and run this script it will save all combinations with that layer placed outside.

now if anyone know here scripting i have one question.

like when we run the script it asks for file name and then it adds incrimental numbers after it like if we written abc in file name then it will save images as  abc1, abc 2 like this

What i want is that if we have written abc in filename and run the script it shud add layer name after it. like if layer names are japan,america, then it shud save files as abcjapan, abcamerica.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cycle through all the layers in your document and set the visibility as needed before exporting the image. To set the visibility you'll need something like this:

```
    for(var layerIndex=0; layerIndex < app.activeDocument.artLayers.length; layerIndex++) {
        var layer=app.activeDocument.artLayers[layerIndex];

        //do some logic to determine if the layer should be visible
            layer.visible = true;
    }
```

And see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032288/using-javascript-to-save-files-in-photoshop-without-a-prompt/33037428#33037428) re: saving your jpeg once you've set the layer visibility as needed.